# I got TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable When run in the first of time

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I am trying to query data from Synapse using pyodbc and read it by pandas with pandas.read_sql
when I run for the first time sometime I got

```
File "C:\****\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2117, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

but when I run that again it runs completely or when I query in Database Tool it also returns data

```
#Connection String to Azure Synapse
def to_synapse():

    server = 'xxxx'
    database = xxxx
    username = xxxx
    password = xxxxx
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

    connection_string = 'DRIVER='+driver+';MARS_Connection=yes;SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=xxxx;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
    
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    return conn

def get_users_df_from_syn():
    __pgdb = to_synapse()
    exe_query = "SELECT * from something"
        df = pd.read_sql(exe_query, __pgdb)
    return df
```

I tried to add a while loop if the dataframe is empty it will run again in 10 seconds. But it doesn't work.
Also, I tried the solution in Stackoverflow but it did not solve my problem.
How do I fix it?

Comment: What purpose is the `to_synapse()` function?  It is never called.  What is `__pgdb`?  That variable is not defined.  It's hard for us to help when you give us incomplete code.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry I edit it  the variable __pgdb call to_synapse() like __pgdb = to_synapse()

Comment: `Also, I tried the solution in Stackoverflow but it did not solve my problem.` Can you explain more? What solution did you try, and how did it fall short?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add a while loop if the dataframe is empty it will run again in 10 seconds. But it doesn't work

You can do something like below in your `get_users_df_from_syn()` function to achieve your requirement.

```
def get_users_df_from_syn():
    __pgdb = to_synapse()
    exe_query = "SELECT * from sample2"
    flag=True
    df = pd.read_sql(exe_query, __pgdb)
    count=0
    while(count<5 and flag):
        if df.empty:
            #your code to change the query as the old query gives empty dataframe
            df = pd.read_sql(exe_query, __pgdb)
            #To Execute the above query count times
            count+=1
        else:
            flag=False          
    return df

get_users_df_from_syn().head()
```

**Result when dataframe is not empty:**

[image]

**Result when dataframe is empty:**

Here, I have not changed the query in the loop, so it iterated 5 times in the loop. You can change the query in the loop to make sure it won't give empty dataframe as per your requirement.

I have given the count to avoid infinite loop if anything is wrong in the query.

[image]